# How to output exactly what is happening when you run a program in Windows?

Tags: windows, logging, cmd, exe

In other words, I want to get a detailed log of everything happened since I ran the executable.

I already tried to enable logging, as it was stated here:

https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO2906.html

but failed to bring me any results, maybe I am mistaking something in the the string registry, I am not sure if I should add all the string value letters with coma in between or not, but both things still have not worked out.

I tried enabling it through Event Viewer, but failed that too.

The command I used now is:

“C:\Program Files\My EXE.exe” /L*v “C:\Program Files\InstallLog.txt” /I

same as the one listed in this article/guide, but it did not worked, even though I enabled Logging in group policy.

Comment: If you want logging, your program has to implement it.  It doesn't happen by magic.

Comment: I am a newbie, so I don't know how to explain in it in higher terms, but you are saying that if a game is executing some section where it obviously increases the workload of the CPU and the GPU at a given time, I cannot actually see what executions it actually does to result in that increment, and all I can know is that Game.exe increased the workload on the CPU and he GPU by a % and that is that?

Comment: You could use free tool [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) of Sysinternals (Microsoft) to log every file system access, registry access, network access, thread and DLL activity, ... of a process (to find out where an error occurs).

Comment: do you really expect a game developer to log what they are doing in detail? That's like "Look, how we do our fancy stuff, so you can create something similar by yourself"

Comment: @Mofi Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Aside question, I see some processes running and have Buffer Overflow in the result section, is that something that I need to be concerned?

Comment: `STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` is a warning that the call didn't succeed because the supplied buffer wasn't big enough. The caller can repeat the call with a larger buffer, or sometimes the incomplete data is enough. For example, `GetFileInformationByHandle` makes two system calls, one of which is `NtQueryInformationFile` to get the `FileAllInformation` for the `File` object. The last field of this data is the `NameInformation`, but it doesn't need it and doesn't allocate space for more than one character. Thus there's almost always a buffer overflow reported for `GetFileInformationByHandle`.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for your answer! I generally saw some at HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink